# Filter Orders in Admin area, based on Custom meta

Tags: plugins

**Story:**

I have custom role `Staff` for my WooCommerce shop,

When a Customer create an Order, the Order is assigned a custom meta name `handle_by` where the value is a random value of user where role is Staff.

When Staff is login and click `WooCoomerce > Orders`, He/She will only see Orders where `handle_by` is match current user id.

**Problem:**

How to filter WooCommerce > Order to only show Order where the custom meta `handle_by` is match with current user login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it, using `pre_get_posts` filter and `WP_Query->set()` method

```
function foo_filter_orders($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;
    
    $currentUserRoles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
    
    if (in_array('shop_manager', $currentUserRoles)) {
        if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 
                isset($qv['post_type']) && $qv['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {            
            $query->set('meta_key', 'handle_by');
            $query->set('meta_value', 'shopmanager1');
        }
    }
    
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'foo_filter_orders');
```

Comment: where `handle_by` ? your answer didnt fully matched the scenarios and can be further improving

Comment: Ahh, true. I have a lot of meta_key with same value while developing it. Fixed to match the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'display_admin_shop_order_language_filter' );
function display_admin_shop_order_language_filter(){
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( 'shop_order' === $post_type && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $domain    = 'woodmart';
        $languages = array(array(__('Ebay', $domain),'ebay_managed_payment')  );
        $current   = isset($_GET['filter_shop_order_payment_method'])? $_GET['filter_shop_order_payment_method'] : '';
        echo '<select name="filter_shop_order_payment_method">
        <option value="">' . __('Filter By Payment Method ', $domain) . '</option>';
        
        foreach ( $languages as $value ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $value[1], 
                $value[1] === $current ? '" selected="selected"' : '', $value[0] );
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'process_admin_shop_order_language_filter' );
function process_admin_shop_order_language_filter( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( $query->is_admin && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset( $_GET['filter_shop_order_payment_method'] ) 
        && $_GET['filter_shop_order_payment_method'] != '' && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {

        //$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' ); // Get the current "meta query"
        /*$meta_query[] = array( // Add to "meta query"
            'meta_key' => '_payment_method',
            'value'    => esc_attr( $_GET['filter_shop_order_payment_method'] ),
        );*/
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => '_payment_method',
                'value' => esc_attr( $_GET['filter_shop_order_payment_method'] ),
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query ); // Set the new "meta query"

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 ); // Set "posts per page"

        $query->set( 'paged', ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) ); // Set "paged"
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it actually answers the question. Is this similar code that could be adapted? Perhaps you could add some explanation to the answer rather than just code.